# `eth_getTransactionReceipt` returns the transaction hash not the receipt

Tags: testing, ganache, truffle-test, receipts, ganache-cli

I use [sol-coverage](https://sol-coverage.com) in a [truffle project](https://github.com/sablierhq/sablier). Ganache is my development blockchain. I have a lot of tests which end up doing more than a few thousand JSON RPC calls.

Due to unbeknownst reasons, the `eth_getTransactionReceipt` command fails to return the receipt object after ~1,000 calls. Instead I get the transaction hash, which breaks sol-coverage, because the expected result is either "null" or an object (as per the [official docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionreceipt)).

Here's the function from the [@0x codebase](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo) where the issue occurs:

```
public async getTransactionReceiptIfExistsAsync(txHash: string): Promise<TransactionReceipt | undefined> {
    assert.isHexString('txHash', txHash);
    const transactionReceiptRpc = await this.sendRawPayloadAsync<TransactionReceiptRPC>({
        method: 'eth_getTransactionReceipt',
        params: [txHash],
    });
    // HACK Parity can return a pending transaction receipt. We check for a non null
    // block number before continuing with returning a fully realised receipt.
    // ref: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/1180
    if (transactionReceiptRpc !== null && transactionReceiptRpc.blockNumber !== null) {
        transactionReceiptRpc.status = Web3Wrapper._normalizeTxReceiptStatus(transactionReceiptRpc.status);
        const transactionReceipt = marshaller.unmarshalTransactionReceipt(transactionReceiptRpc);
        return transactionReceipt;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

And my environment:

- ganache-cli 6.6.0
- sol-coverage 3.0.10
- truffle 5.0.34

It this a bug with ganache?

Comment: Please show the relevant code (Solidity and Javascript) - wild guess - you forgot an `await`.

Comment: It's not my code, it's 0x's. I updated the answer.

Comment: This is not Javascript, while both Truffle and Solidity-Coverage are Javascript-based projects. What's the deal here?

Comment: @goodvibration's you're confusing 0x's [sol-coverage](https://sol-coverage.com) with sc-forks's [solidity-coverage](https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage). sol-coverage is written in Typescript.

Comment: Oh, I don't know why `truffle test` doesn't break but `MODE=coverage truffle test` does. That's why I asked the question and I mentioned that it happens specifically when I measure test coverage.

Comment: I don't see any contract in your question, and I don't see any Truffle test either, which makes it rather impossible to refer to your question in details.

Comment: It's not about one contract or one truffle test, it's about all tests in the [Sablier codebase](https://github.com/sablierhq/sablier). I mentioned that the error occurs after 1,000 JSON RPC calls. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: What versions are you using in your project (solidity-coverage, truffle, ganache)?

Comment: I updated the question. It's not solidity-coverage, but sol-coverage.

Comment: If it works with ganache it looks like a bug is sol-coverage better to report it in their github.